# How can I disable the default RichTextBox command for Ctrl+1?

Tags: wpf, richtextbox, commandbinding

Snoop shows that the command is "ApplySingleSpace", but when I try disabling it via the method described in [this article](http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/34644/1954) . Like this:

```
<RichTextBox.CommandBindings>
     <CommandBinding 
       Command="ApplySingleSpace" 
       CanExecute="BlockTheCommand"/>
   </RichTextBox.CommandBindings>
```

.

```
  private void BlockTheCommand(object sender,
     CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
   {
     e.CanExecute = false;
     e.Handled = true;
   }
```

My app crashes because there is no `ApplySingleSpace` command. `ApplySingleSpace` is not in the `EditingCommands` either.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Unfortunately that will not work for
>   me. The reason I am trying to disable
>   the command is that I have a
>   KeyBinding in a higher nested view
>   that is not firing because the CTRL+1
>   gesture is being swallowed by the
>   richtextbox which has keyboardfocus.

How about overwriting that KeyBinding with a custom command that does what you want instead of trying to somehow disable it?

```
<RichTextBox.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Command="local:YourCommands.Cmd1" Gesture="CTRL+1" />
<RichTextBox.InputBindings>
```

Taken from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4200553/keybinding-gesture-ctrl1-in-richtextbox-doesnt-work).

Comment: Ah. I was hoping for a more elegant way of doing it, but I don't have any more time to spare on it. Why in the world did MS think it was a good idea to add these commands without there being an option to disable them?

Answer (score 1):

Using the code from this answer 
[How can I programmatically generate keypress events in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1645815/how-can-i-programmatically-generate-keypress-events-in-c)
to refire all events on PreviewKeyDown other than those you want handled by the richtextbox seems to work for me. (I only need Ctrl-C for copy). Of course you could make it so it only refires Ctrl-1 if that's what you need.

```
private void logKeyHandler(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (!(Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Control && e.Key == Key.C))
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        var routedEvent = Keyboard.KeyDownEvent; 
        this.RaiseEvent(
            new KeyEventArgs(
            Keyboard.PrimaryDevice, 
            PresentationSource.FromDependencyObject(this),
            0,
            e.Key) { RoutedEvent = routedEvent }
        );
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

What about trying with the gesture instead...

```
        <RichTextBox.InputBindings>
            <KeyBinding Command="BlockTheCommand" Gesture="CTRL+1" />
        </RichTextBox.InputBindings>
```

Comment: Unfortunately that will not work for me. The reason I am trying to disable the command is that I have a KeyBinding in a higher nested view that is not firing because the CTRL+1 gesture is being swallowed by the richtextbox which has keyboardfocus.

Comment: @Justin The code above is no different then your first approach; since a given command is tied to a gesture. I'm curious if you did the above; did nothing in the handler would the framework command execute or would it make its way up stream?

Comment: If I bind the gesture to a new command like that, the new command fires and swallows the CTRL-1 gesture. The ApplySingleSpace does not fire. If I make it so that the BlockTheCommand can't execute, it still swallows the gesture.